# Slight difference in the pmf of the Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

I can see on the Wikipedia page of the Poisson distribution that the pmf is given by

$$ P(X=k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

However, I'm working through a worksheet for my university and I see it given like this:

$$ P(X=\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

Is this a mistake or does it not make a difference?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is irrelevant for other readers.

Comment: I am unable to find this error anywhere on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) but in numerous places I see the correct formula, leaving no doubt as to the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is definitely a mistake. $\lambda$ is the *parameter* of the Poisson distribution, which can take any positive value. $k$ is *a possible outcome*, which can only take a nonnegative *integer* value.